# How to find dates of fridays in a month and dates in a month in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am developing a app which uses the date, month, year. I want the current month friday dates and current month dates,because current month can have 28,29,30,31 days. I have tried to get current year months with current year. but i don't know the code for above. here is my code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSDate           *today           = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar       *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *yearComponents  = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  fromDate:today];
int currentYear  = [yearComponents year];
for(int months = 0; months < 12; months++)
{
    NSString *monthName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols]objectAtIndex: months],currentYear];
    NSLog(@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols]objectAtIndex: months],currentYear);
    [monthArray addObject:monthName];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSDateComponents` in combination with `NSCalendar's` `dateFromComponents`: method:

Try like something like,

```
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [c setYear:2013];
    [c setWeekday:6];//1=sun,2=mon .....
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        [c setMonth:i];
        for (int j=1; j<=5; j++)
        {
            [c setWeekdayOrdinal:j];
            NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:c];
            NSLog(@"Date[%i]: %@",i,date);

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's worked for me. Can you give me answer for getting dates of current month?

Comment: just set `setMonth` to current month of NSDateComponents.

Comment: I tried it. but it shows current date only. :(          NSDateComponents *d = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [d setYear:2013];
    [d setMonth:10];
    
    NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:d];
    NSLog(@"Date1: %@",date1);

Comment: have you try in loop with `setWeekday`?

Comment: No. If i added a loop how can i pass the limit for loop. Because a month can have 28,29,30,31 days??

Comment: `NSDate *date = [NSDate date];//as your are forming date, put it here
NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange weekRange = [calender rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:date];
NSInteger weeksCount=weekRange.length;
NSLog(@"%d",weeksCount);`

Comment: Are understand my question? You are giving suggestion about getting week days. It working for me. But i am asking about getting dates for month. For example if its october month i want dates 01-10-2013 to 31-10-2013. I want code for generating this dates.

Comment: oh man .. your question is to find firday, now you are asking for another.. please ask it as new question or search related to it..